# Counting measure over a set?

Tags: measure-theory

We know that if $\tau$ is the counting measure, on, say, the natural numbers, then $$\int f d \tau = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$ ... but what if we take the integral over a set like $(-\infty ,x)$, where $x$ is not necessarily a natural number?

Answer (score 2):

You can only take the integral over a (measurable) subset of the measure space. If the space $A$ is the integers, there is no set like $(-\infty, x) \subset A$, where $x$ isn't an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you define your measurable space.

For example, if $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B},\mu)$ such that $\mu(A)=\#\big(A\cap \mathbb{N}\big)$, then your integral is well defined. For a $\mu$-integrable function $f$ $$\int_A f\mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{n\in A\cap \mathbb{N}} f(n).$$